# Rails Parsing RSS Feed Feedzirra / Feedjira with simple_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feedzirra

I'm using Feedjira (Feedzirra) https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira to parse rss feeds in rails.

I need a way to remove html tags from the title of the rss feed items before I save to database.

in my create method which saves the feed item to the database

```
:title => feed_items_url.title
```

I tried to add simple_format to this but it didn't work

```
:name => simple_format(feed_items_url.title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nokogiri and the method `text` which will strip the HTML tags from your content.

```
@doc.title().text
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a built-in helper for strip HTML tags: [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags).

```
strip_tags(feed_items_url.title)
```